# How to correctly iterate over a std::set of pointers to 'MyClass' in C++ and what requirements should 'MyClass' meet for valid iteration?

Tags: c++, c++14, stdset

I'm working with a `std::set<Employee*, Employee::EmployeeComparator >`.
First here is the Class `Manager`:

```
class Manager : public Employee
{
public:
    //C'tors & d'tor//
    Manager(int id, std::string first_name, std::string last_name, int year);
    Manager(const Manager& other) = default;
    ~Manager() = default;

    //Methods//
[...]


private:
    std::set<Employee*, Employee::EmployeeComparator > m_employees;
};
```

```
    class EmployeeComparator {
    public:
        bool operator()(const Employee* emp1, const Employee* emp2) const {
            return emp1->getId() < emp2->getId();
        }
    };
```

Now, I'm trying to iterate over `m_employee` and erase all of them from the set:

```
void Manager::fireEmployees(int salary_to_reduce) {
    for (auto it = m_employees.begin(); it != m_employees.end(); ++it) {
        (*it)->setSalary(-salary_to_reduce);
        m_employees.erase(*it);
    }
}
```

**the `m_employees.erase` failed:**

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFBDD097FBC (ucrtbased.dll) in Citizens
> Management System (C++ training).exe: An invalid parameter was passed
> to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.

[image with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aG2Gp.png)

*The error also opens a file called 'xtree,' which I assume is part of the set implementation.

is the class `Manager` should meet special requirements that I'm not aware of?
is the functor written correctly?

Any guidance on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `m_employees.erase(*it);` followed by `++it` will not work. Do `it = m_employees.erase(it);` and do not do `++it` afterwards - It would however be easier if you stored `std::unique_ptr<Employee>` in the `set`. You could then just `clear()` it.

Comment: don't modify a container while iterating over it.  Use the erase-remove idiom instead

Comment: Also I would base my comparator on references not pointers.

Comment: If you are trying to erase the full contents of the set, just use `std::set::clear()`. I don't currently see the point of the salary reduction instruction, as they are being removed anyway. But if it is  needed, do that alone in a loop, then call the set's clear() function.

Comment: All of this other advice is relevant if you are picking and choosing what to erase.

Comment: A side note: why do you update the salary (`(*it)->setSalary(-salary_to_reduce);`), if the element is immediately removed anyway ?

Comment: *"is the class `Manager` should meet special requirements that I'm not aware of?"* -- The process of constructing a [mre] should have answered this for you, as one of the simplifications you should have tried is getting rid of the `Manager` class. (Instead, define your set in your `main` function, populate it via a function call, then execute your `for` loop.)